# Python - sqlite3 cannot select right after update-commit - works on retry

Tags: python, sqlite

```
tst = dbConnection.execute("SELECT nameshort, namefull, timelastpostsecs, qtypostlasttime 
FROM " + tableToUse + " WHERE compid = ?", (str(row['compid']),))
```

Give following error when run 3rd time in cycle where `row` is different each time:

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably
>   unsupported type.

Select is run right after `update` - `commit` to check update.

When I copy code from error message and execute it again in IDE Python (where I run script), it works w/out error.

What could it mean? 
I understand I can add `try` and then retry in case of exception, still maybe there is better way.

ADDED: added `try:` and see that error persists at each cycle loop after 3rd update. After waiting 5 seconds and trying again select works. So kind of for this code (which is not time critical) issue is worked around. Still I'm interested if it's known issue with sqlite.

Comment: Could you provide some samples of `row` that cause it to fail?

Comment: Broadly there are at least two parts of the statement that could be causing the error, and both depend on data. `str(row['compid'])` is being fed into the query, and something could be going wrong there with encodings. The execution of the `SELECT` could have something going wrong with encodings or timestamps (especially if there's a timezone issue). These are both things that your IDE may be handling for you behind the scenes. It's not immediately clear why it's working on the third try, but we need to see more context.

Comment: @Feneric, I edited the question. Also, nameshort, namefull - are char(100,150) with russian language phrases, timelastpostsecs, qtypostlasttime, compid - integer. Update for timelastpostsecs, qtypostlasttime.

Comment: @Feneric, thank you for help. One thing I don't understand - why you talk about timezone as sqlite do not have datetime type. I hope that adding detail about select after update provides context you talked about.

Comment: Just spitting out examples. Again, I don't have context. If you're trying to feed a Python datetime into it it'll have troubles. From what you're saying I'd look for encoding issues.