# Python sqlite loop index out of range

Tags: python, sqlite, loops

```
dbCursor = dbConnection.execute("SELECT compid, " + rowToUse + ", nameshort, namefull FROM " + tableToUse + " WHERE " + rowToUse + " IS NOT NULL")

dbCursor1 = dbConnection.execute("SELECT compid, " + rowToUse + ", nameshort, namefull FROM " + tableToUse + " WHERE " + rowToUse + " IS NOT NULL")
myList = dbCursor1.fetchall()
myRange = [i for i in range(len(myList))] # [[i] for i in range(len(myList))]

myRangeCurrent = 0

for row1 in dbCursor:
    row = myList[myRange[myRangeCurrent]]
    myRangeCurrent = myRangeCurrent + 1
```

Gave me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#176>", line 1, in
<module>
    row = myList[myRange[myRangeCurrent]] IndexError: list index out of range
```

Range should last exactly as cycle as was made on same select query. Or not?

Comment: Please correct `[i for i in range(len(myList))]` to just `list(range(len(myList)))`

Comment: Please explain what you are attempting to achieve with both or either cursors.

Comment: It's not even clear why you need `myRange`... you can use `for i, row in enumerate(dbCursor.fetchAll())`

Comment: @cricket_007, thank you for shorter code, but IDE shoes result is the same

Comment: If we're nitpicking you could just iterate the cursor to start with instead of storing the range, then the fetchall, then trying to index `myList` with `myRange` to begin with and you could also do `myRangeCurrent += 1`  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Parfait, surely there is a lot of other code inside loop, but it does not attempt to edit row and/or row1. I want to access table as both sequestially and also get data at specific location in table.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov He/She is asking you to provide a [mcve]. Having two cursor that run the same query is not minimal

Comment: @cricket_007, it's second 'glitch' for today for me. Previus here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414530/python-sqlite3-cannot-select-right-after-update-commit-works-on-retry. Maybe my database is corrupted or what. I wanted to confirm I understand Python ranges correctly.

Comment: What is there to understand? It returns a list of numbers... https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Answer (score 0):

Check your SQL queries are correct (hint: you only need one cursor since your queries are the same) and print out the result of `fetchall`, then try this to print out the rows and their indices.

```
for i, row in enumerate(dbCursor.fetchall()):
    print(i, row)
```

Although, you should be able to do this as well

```
for i, row in enumerate(dbCursor):
    print(i, row)
```

Comment: print (dbCursor)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000005071F80>. Then your for:
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'fetchAll'

Comment: Oops, typo. Okay, great. You printed the cursor object... So, loop over its results.

Comment: In IDE I run 
>>>dbCursor01 = dbConnection.execute("SELECT 
>>>hy = dbCursor01.fetchall()
>>>print len(hy)
say 200
>>> for i, row in enumerate(dbCursor01.fetchall()):
    print(i, row)
Give me empty result

Comment: Android only uses one Cursor as well, so I think you misunderstood something when learning that.

Comment: I opened my old Andoid code, you are right here, thanx for correcting..

Comment: Don't use `len` before you iterate the cursor. It gives you empty result because you already exhausted the iterator

Comment: >>> len (c01.fetchall())
Some number
>>> list (enumerate(c01.fetchall()))
[]
>>> len (c01.fetchall())
0
Looks like cursor is released after being accessed. Why could that be?

Comment: "Don't use len before you iterate the cursor." on last comment I run fetchall() each time. Still exchausted?

Comment: Stop using len... Use `cursor.rowcount` as I already said, using `len` exhausts the iterator by looping over the cursor and counting that

Comment: So you see cursor object can be changed and having two sometimes can make sense? I wander now why then my code gave out or range only on last loop, not on first.

Comment: You only need one cursor and use the API correctly. That seems to be the problem

Comment: And in the code of your original question, you only called `fetchall` once. After you do that, you will always get a `len` of 0 because there is nothing left to iterate in the cursor

Comment: But `myList[myRange[myRangeCurrent]]` worked for hundreds of iterations before out of range,

Comment: And after making new c03 cursor, `>>>c03.rowcount gave` -1. Why? After fetchall - same -1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117510/discussion-between-alexei-martianov-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

cricket_007 explained that obtaining `len` from cursor changes cursor, so I changed code adding one more cursor. Now no more `out of range`:

```
mySQL = "SELECT compid, " + rowToUse + ", nameshort, namefull FROM " + tableToUse + " WHERE " + rowToUse + " IS NOT NULL"

dbCursor = dbConnection.execute(mySQL)
dbCursor1 = dbConnection.execute(mySQL)
dbCursor2 = dbConnection.execute(mySQL)

myList = dbCursor1.fetchall()
myList2 = dbCursor2.fetchall()
myRange = list(range(len(myList2)))

myRangeCurrent = 0

for row1 in dbCursor:
    row = myList[myRange[myRangeCurrent]]
    myRangeCurrent = myRangeCurrent + 1
```